# Prove: $\tan{\frac{x}{2}}\sec{x}= \tan{x} - \tan{\frac{x}{2}}$

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

I was solving a question which required the above identity to proceed but I never found its proof anywhere. I tried to prove it but got stuck after a while.

I reached till here:

To Prove: $$\tan{\frac{x}{2}}\sec{x}= \tan{x} - \tan{\frac{x}{2}}$$
[image: Solving]

But I don't know what to do next.
Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: There is a useful identity $$\tan\left(\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right)=\frac{\sin(\theta)}{1+\cos(\theta)}=\frac{1-\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}\,.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\tan \dfrac x2\sec x=\dfrac{\sin\dfrac x2}{\cos\dfrac x2\cdot\cos x}$$

Use $\sin\dfrac x2=\sin\left(x-\dfrac x2\right)=?$

Answer (score 4):

For fun, here's a trigonographic solution:

[image]

$$|\triangle ORS| = |\triangle OTS| - |\triangle OTR| \;\to\;
\color{gray}{\tfrac12}\cdot\tan\theta\cdot\sec2\theta=\color{gray}{\tfrac12}\cdot 1\cdot\tan2\theta-\color{gray}{\tfrac12}\cdot1\cdot\tan\theta$$

Comment: That was really fun to solve! I never proved any identity by geometry except the basic ones.

Comment: @KaustubhGupta: I'm glad you like it. :) I have a number of these kinds of diagrams on [trigonography.com](https://trigonography.com). I've neglected that site for a while, but I think the above figure would make a nice addition. Thanks for bringing that identity to my attention.

Comment: That would be really nice to add. Glad I could help.:D

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

use [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution#The_substitution)

$$\tan\dfrac x2\sec x+\tan\dfrac x2=\tan\dfrac x2\left(\dfrac{1+\tan^2\dfrac x2}{1-\tan^2\dfrac x2}+1\right)=?$$

Answer (score 0):

In terms of $t=\tan\tfrac{x}{2}$, the LHS is $t\cdot\frac{1+t^2}{1-t^2}$, while the RHS is $\frac{2t}{1-t^2}-t=t\cdot\frac{2-(1-t^2)}{1-t^2}=t\cdot\frac{1+t^2}{1-t^2}$.